# How to deal with global parameters in a scientific Python script

Tags: python, class, variables, parameter-passing

I am writing a piece of scientific software in Python which comprises both a Poisson equation solver (using the Newton method) on a rectangular mesh, and a particle-in-cell code. I've written the Newton Solver and the particle-in-cell code as separate functions, which are called by my main script.

I had originally written the code as one large script, but decided to break up the script so that it was more modular, and so that the individual functions could be called on their own. My problem is that I have a large number of "global" variables which I consider parameters for the problem. This includes mostly problem constants and parameters which define the problem geometry and mesh (such as dimensions, locations of certain boundary conditions, boundary conditions etc.).

These parameters are required by both the main script and the individual functions. My question is: What is the best way (and most proper) to store these variables such that they can be accessed by both the main script and the functions.

My current solution is to define a class in a separate module (parameters.py) as so:

```
class Parameters:
    length = 0.008
    width = 0.0014

    nz = 160
    nr = 28

    dz = length/nz
    dr = width/nr
    ...
```

In my main script I then have:

```
from parameters import Parameters

par = Parameters()

coeff_a = -2 * (1/par.dr**2 + 1/par.dz**2)
...
```

This method allows me to then use `par` as a container for my parameters which can be passed to any functions I want. It also provides an easy way to easily set up the problem space to run just one of the functions on their own. My only concern is that each function does not require everything stored in `par`, and hence it seems inefficient passing it forward all the time. I could probably remove many of the parameters from par, but then I would need to recalculate them every time a function is called, which seems even more inefficient.

Is there a standard solution which people use in these scenarios? I should mention that my functions are not changing the attributes of par, just reading them. I am also interested in achieving high performance, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, when your program requires many parameters in different places, it makes sense to come up with a neat configuration system, usually a class that provides a certain interface to your own code.

Upon instantiation of that class, you have a configuration object at hand which you can pass around. In some places you might want to populate it, in other places you just might want to use it. In any case, this configuration object will be globally accessible. If your program is a Python package, then this configuration mechanism might be written in its own module which you can import from all other modules in your package.

The configuration class might provide useful features such as parameter registration (a certain code section says that it needs a certain parameter to be set), definition of defaults and parameter validation.

The actual population of parameters is then based on defaults, user-given commandline arguments or user-given input files.

Answer (score 0):

To make *Jan-Philip Gehrcke*'s answer more figurative, check out [A global class pattern for python](https://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2010/10/20/a-globals-class-pattern-for-python/) (btw: it's just a normal class, nothing special about "global" - but you can pass it around "globally").

Before actually implementing this in my own program, I had the same idea but wanted to find out how others would do it (like questioner *nicholls*). I was a bit skeptical to implement this in the first place, in particular it looked quite strange to instantiate a class in the module itself. But it works fine.

However, there are some things to keep in mind though:

- It is not super clean. For instance, someone that doesn't know the function in your module wouldn't expect that a parameter in a configuration class needs to be set
- If you have to reload your module/functions but want to maintain the values set in your configuration class, you should not instantiate the configuration class again: `if "mem" not in locals(): mem = Mem()`
- It's not advised to assign a parameter from your configuration class as a default argument for a function. For example `function(a, b=mem.defaultB)`.
  You cannot change this default value later after initialization. Instead, do `function(a, b=None): if b is None: b=mem.defaultB`. Then you can also adjust your configuration class after you loaded your module/functions.
- Certainly there are more issues...